# .htaccess to rewrite image urls

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello im having a problem with images in my wordpress directory with a plug-in that doesnt have much support, i've fixed most bits but the images. I know would have to alter my .htaccess in the root but im not sure how.

Heres what my current .htaccess looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My site doesnt load up the images in the plugin, when inspecting the sourcecode on chrome its looking for an image at the following URL, which gives a 404 error.

http://www.example.com//http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/wprx/wpt_image.php?i=/wp-content/wpt_cache/7/1713/01.jpg

The correct URL for the image would be:

http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/wprx/wpt_image.php?i=/wp-content/wpt_cache/7/1713/01.jpg

any ideas on altering the .htaccess to remove the "http://www.example.com//" from the start of the URL?

Many Thanks,
Pete

Comment: You should probably track down and fix the problem causing this to happen. Is it definitely a problem with the plugin or could it be a mistake in your theme file?

Answer (score 2):

#### Disclaimer:

While what you're asking is **possible**, you should not choose this solution, but instead **find and resolve the cause** of your problem.
Because the browser will still be looking for

```
http://www.example.com//http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/wprx/wpt_image.php?i=/wp-content/wpt_cache/7/1713/01.jpg
```

after this, you will only provide it with a file then.

## This is a bad solution!

---

#### How to:

In the path passed to the .htaccess file, the protocol, host and port have already been stripped, leaving you with

```
//http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/wprx/wpt_image.php?i=/wp-content/wpt_cache/7/1713/01.jpg
```

so you really want to remove the *second* `http://www.example.com`.
Putting the following line right after `RewriteBase` should make it kind of work:

```
RewriteRule ^//http://www.example.com/(.*)$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your htaccess like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# fix images path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (http://.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]    

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```